# Cannot understand why total SS＝explained SS+unexplained SS

Tags: regression, anova, least-squares, linear, sums-of-squares

I cannot understand why total SS＝explained SS+unexplained SS because geometrically the sum of two small squares is not equal to a big square.
I wish someone could explain that to me. Thank you.

Comment: Geometrically this is called the *Pythagorean Theorem.*  There exist some [very pretty geometric proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem), going back to Euclid, showing exactly how the sum of (areas) of two small squares equals the area of a big square.

Comment: Related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265869/confused-with-residual-sum-of-squares-and-total-sum-of-squares and more linked from that question

Comment: Thank you, guys.

Comment: One caveat, this decomposition holds only for models containing an intercept.  If your model doesn't have an intercept, then this relationship no longer holds.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Added to my answer

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/494274/247274) question of mine has several answers that discuss the details why, but the gist is that, for a linear model (WITH AN INTERCEPT), the minimization of the residual sum of squares forces the explained and unexplained vectors to be orthogonal, and then the Pythagorean theorem applies to a right triangle. Then [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551916/247274) post of mine gives the decomposition of the total sum of squares; in the language of that post, the orthogonality means that the $Other$ term equals zero. (That entire decomposition can be viewed as the law of cosines, where the $Other$ term corresponds to the term with the cosine in it, so zero when the vectors are orthogonal.)